# Uploading to a Git Repository

Tags: git

The repositories that I was using was in a particular organization. It was moved to new organization a couple of days back. Since then I am facing issues pushing code to the repository. I am a member of the new organization. I tried the following commands, got these errors:

```
1) git remote set-url <name_of_local_folder> <new_organization_repo_URL>
   fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

2)  git remote -v 
    origin  <new_organization_repo_URL> (fetch)
    origin  <new_organization_repo_URL> (push)

    git push origin <branch_name>
    remote: Repository not found.
    fatal: repository '<new_organization_repo_URL>' not found
```

Can someone suggest how to solve this?

Comment: It looks like new one is not a valid link to a git repo. Could you please try to checkout a new repo to a separate directory and compare remotes?

Comment: Does it literally say `fatal: repository '<new_organization_repo_URL>' not found`?

Answer (score 2):

```
1) git remote set-url <name_of_local_folder> <new_organization_repo_URL>
   fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

The error is because you're not in a directory with a Git repository. You have to change directories to your repository directory first.

Once you're in the correct directory, you can change the URL to your remote. `git remote set-url` does not take the name of the local folder. It takes the name of the remote to change. By default this is `origin`.

```
git remote set-url origin <new_organization_repo_URL>
```

Substitute `<new_organization_repo_URL>` with the new URL to your repository. Something like `https://github.com/org/repo.git`. It will be in the "Clone or download" button on the repository's Github page.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was some permission issues. The organization owner reassigned the permissions and then all is good. But I also used `git remote set-url origin <new_organization_repo_URL>` to set the URL.